# How to use OR condition in ngIf in angular?

Tags: angular, angular6

Suppose I have the logic inside the component.ts:

```
 selectInput(event) {
    let selected = event.target.value;

    if (selected == "firm") {
      this.isNameSelected = true;
    } else if(selected == "consignment") {
      this.isNameSelected = false;
      this.labelForCP=true;
    }
    else{
      this.tash=true;
       this.isNameSelected = false;
        this.labelForCP=false;
    }
  }
```

And in my html i have:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4" *ngIf="!isNameSelected">
```

i tried to combine `*ngIf="!isNameSelected || tash"` but I am getting the **error** in console as i cant apply this kind of method. I want the condition if anyone of the condition is `true(OR condition)` it must enter inside the section.

Comment: What error do you get? I can't see why you couldn't combine the two as you did

Comment: Not set 'selected' as methods variable, use it as components field with 'null'. Something like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-trjmcx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ngIf works pretty much in the same way like a normal If condition works. Below is an example.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4" *ngIf="!condition1 || condition2">
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4" *ngIf="!(isNameSelected===true || tash ===true)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple as normal if condition, below one should work

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4" *ngIf="isNameSelected === false || otherCondition === true">
```